# The ListView has columns added by the SPFx Field Customizer?

Tags: spfx, custom-list

I have added a column to the list view using the SPFx field customizer.
It's not display in the list view.
How can I determine in the onInit() event of the SPFx ListView Command Set if the ListView has columns added by the SPFx Field Customizer?

```
@override
public onInit(): Promise<void> {
    return Promise.resolve();
}
@override
public onRenderCell(event: IFieldCustomizerCellEventParameters): void {
        event.domElement.innerText = "test";
        event.domElement.classList.add(styles.testSytle);
  }
@override
public onDisposeCell(event: IFieldCustomizerCellEventParameters): void {
    super.onDisposeCell(event);
  }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <Field ID="{xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx}"
            Name="testApp"
            DisplayName="testColumn"
            Type="Number"
            Min="0"
            Required="FALSE"
            Group="TestApp Columns"
            ClientSideComponentId="xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx"
            ClientSideComponentProperties="{
            }">
    </Field>
</Elements>
```

Comment: Can you show us the code, how you added a column to the list view using the SPFx field customizer?

Comment: Thank you!! Is this alright with you?

Comment: Did you include/show the column in list view from list view settings in SharePoint?

Comment: yes, I did.  I add column to the ListView in this way →  [Deploy the field to SharePoint Online and host JavaScript from local host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-field-customizer#deploy-the-field-to-sharepoint-online-and-host-javascript-from-local-host)

Answer (score 0):

- SPFx ListView Command Set and SPFx field customizer both are two different type of extension in SPFx.
- After deployment of field customizer, you will require to add the site column in SharePoint list manually.
- Make sure that field customizer column name is unique across site.
- Details description is given below on Microsoft docs.

  [building-simple-field-customizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-field-customizer)
- In onInit() method using graph api you can check list of column detials
- Sample api to check list of column using graph api

```
   GET /sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/columns
```